# Firebase flutter real-time search users

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to implement a real time search in my app based on the users of the firebase collection.

In the users collection each user have a specific document.

My question is when a search is done does the number of reads on firestore match the total number of users?

For example:

- total users: 100;
- if a user does a search every day: 100 x 100 = 10000 reads?

In this case i want to reduce the number of reads. Some tips? Is my concept of search wrong? Because i don't want to read all this document, i just need the basic information like 'username', 'picture'

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1):

> If you read 10 documents, you will be charged for 10 reads.

If your user search for another user based on any *"key"*, the number of **documents** (users in your case) returned from the query will be the number of reads

---

For example:
Total Users = 100
User Document fields = name, age

Now if one of your users searches another user based on age (*let's say he searches for users less than 20 years of age*).

Number of users less than 20 years age = 45 (*an example*)
This whole search would then be counted as **45 reads.**

If the same search is done by all your 100 users then the total read count would be
**45 * 100 = 4500 reads**

---

**Related:** Read about pagination [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-96d6cc11aef2)